# How to get enough response from Facebook users who are intended to study abroad?

Tags: user-engagement, communication, experienced-members, social-network, expert-users

We run a social network for college applicants, enabling applicants to connect and collaborate with other applicants, current college students, college alumni, and university officials.

We are going to host a live webinar about studying abroad.
We want to know about webinar topics or what people want to know about studying abroad.

Facebook is the biggest market for finding people. So how to get enough response from Facebook users who have the intention to study abroad?